# xamarin android app crashes after multitasking

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have finished my first xamarin android mobile app. It all works fine. I have only one problem that I cannot solve and I could not find solution using google.

When I start my app it all works great but when I press home button, open and close few other apps and come back to app it crashes. Also when I open app and go turn off my screen and then I turn it back on and to back to app it creshes.

Besides that all works great and there is no crashes. 
This crash is happening both on emulator and on physical device.

The error I get when this happens on emulator is this:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.name.appname/com.name.android.publish.OverlayActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

How to solve this if possible?

Edit:
AndoirdManifest.xml file looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.name.tournamentorganizer" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionName="1.1" android:versionCode="2">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon11" android:name="android.app.Application" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:label="Create new tournament" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light" android:name="md57e31db4bba5ea713128b60ee6f3868c2.createNewTournament" />
    <activity android:label="Tournament Organizer" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light" android:name="md57e31db4bba5ea713128b60ee6f3868c2.MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:label="Add new players" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light" android:name="md5a2089f5b800658a06dd2a11fca5a1f83.addNewPlayers" />
    <activity android:label="addGoalScorer" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light" android:name="md54d075dbf8b437fae408fa9e57e2203ba.addGoalScorer" />
    <activity android:label="All fixtures and results" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light" android:name="md54d075dbf8b437fae408fa9e57e2203ba.allFixturesAndResults" />
    <activity android:label="Players database" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light" android:name="md54d075dbf8b437fae408fa9e57e2203ba.allPlayersActivity" />
    <activity android:label="knockout4Players" android:name="md54d075dbf8b437fae408fa9e57e2203ba.knockout4Players" />
    <activity android:label="League" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light" android:name="md54d075dbf8b437fae408fa9e57e2203ba.leagueType" />
    <activity android:label="My tournaments" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light" android:name="md54d075dbf8b437fae408fa9e57e2203ba.myTournaments" />
    <activity android:label="About" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light" android:name="md54d075dbf8b437fae408fa9e57e2203ba.settings" />
    <activity android:label="Player Info" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light" android:name="md54d075dbf8b437fae408fa9e57e2203ba.stats" />
    <activity android:label="table" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light" android:name="md54d075dbf8b437fae408fa9e57e2203ba.table" />
    <activity android:label="Top scorers" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light" android:name="md54d075dbf8b437fae408fa9e57e2203ba.topScorerActivity" />
    <activity android:label="Winners" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light" android:name="md54d075dbf8b437fae408fa9e57e2203ba.winnersActivity" />
    <activity android:label="winnersAllTimeActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light" android:name="md54d075dbf8b437fae408fa9e57e2203ba.winnersAllTimeActivity" />
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="2147483647" android:authorities="com.name.tournamentorganizer.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
    <!--suppress ExportedReceiver-->
    <receiver android:name="mono.android.Seppuku">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="mono.android.intent.action.SEPPUKU" />
        <category android:name="mono.android.intent.category.SEPPUKU.com.name.tournamentorganizer" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <meta-data android:name="android.support.VERSION" android:value="25.4.0" />
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Edit2:

I have app version with and without ads. The one without ads does not have this issue. The one with ads does have issue so the ads are problem somehow. I am using startapp ads.

Answer (score 0):

you don't probably use the `[Activity]` code adornment

```
[Activity]
internal class YourActivity: Activity {}
```

Comment: this is not possible otherwise it would crash the instant the acitivity is called

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by that. All of my activities look like this:
 [Activity(Theme = "theme", Label = "name", MainLauncher = true)]
 public class MainActivity : Activity {}

Answer (score 0):

If all your activities have

```
[Activity(Theme = "theme", Label = "name", MainLauncher = true)]
```

the MainLauncher argument set to true you will run into trouble.

The Activity annotation is used by Xamarin to configure/generate the AndroidManifest.xml

Have you included a MainApplication class, also tagged with the [Application] attribute? Looking at your manifest I am surprised to see the line

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon11" android:name="android.app.Application" android:debuggable="true">
```

with android:name="android.app.Application". I would expect to see something with an md5 hash (i.e. md5xxx.MainApplication - or whatever the name of your Application class is)

A Clean and Rebuild maybe necessary after changing your application class

Comment: That was mistake. The MainLauncher = true part is only set on main activity as it should be. I added android manifest file into to question.

Comment: I don't quite understan what you mean by that. Where can I find MainApplication class? And how do I change it? 
This problem is really frustrating, can't find solution anywhere.

Comment: I have edited my question with important info - this all happens because of startapp ads.

Comment: Ok, if this is startapp related, you should probably open a new question regarding it, as the above answer is not relevant. How have you bound the startapp sdk? via the .jar file with a binding library?

Comment: It was related to return ad. I had to change screen rotation option to make it work. Anyway, I decided to switch to admob so everything works good now.